# How to read data from Oracle Db using JdbcCursorItemReader with Multi threading

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I had spring batch application and configured step like this:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(4);
taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .<Mymodel, Mymodel>chunk(2500)              
            .reader(reader())
            .writer(writer())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor)
            .build();
```

And reader like this:

```
@Bean
public JdbcCursorItemReader<Mymodel> reader() {
    JdbcCursorItemReader<Mymodel> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<Mymodel>();
    reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
    reader.setSql("select * from User");
    reader.setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Mymodel.class));
    reader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
    return reader;
}
```

When I execute application , getting this error:

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Attempt to process next 
>   row failed; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select * from User]; SQL 
>   state [99999]; error code [17289]; Result set after last row; nested 
>   exception is java.sql.SQLException: Result set after last row

Can you please help me to solve this.

Comment: Yes, per my experience and observations above combination doesn't seem to be working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JdbcCursorItemReader` is [not thread-safe](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.html) as it wraps a `ResultSet` object which is not thread safe.

You can use a `JdbcPagingItemReader` which [is thread safe](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html) and optionally configure the page size to match the chunk size so that each page is processed in the same thread.

More details in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28724199/5019386.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I tried above approach, my application able to read configured page size and remaining records will not processed. I had added task executor as well. if I give page size as 2000 , application able to process 6000 records and stopped processing. Please help me.

Comment: That's another issue, so please ask a different question on SO. My answer should have fixed your issue with the `JdbcCursorItemReader`, if it is the case, please accept it and I will try to help you with your question regarding the `JdbcPaginingItemReader`.

Comment: Sure, Can you help me any example having JdbcPaginingItemReader, some reason I am not able to proceed with next page.

Comment: You can find an example of how to use the `JdbcPagingItemReader` here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/jobs/iosample/jdbcPaging.xml