# StoredProcedureItemReader MultiThreading Exception

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch

I am using Spring Batch StoredProcedureItemReader to retrive the result set and insert it to another database using JpaItemWriter.
Below is my code configuration.

```
@Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader jdbcCursorItemReader(){
        JdbcCursorItemReader jdbcCursorItemReader = new JdbcCursorItemReader();
        jdbcCursorItemReader.setSql("call myProcedure");
        jdbcCursorItemReader.setRowMapper(new MyRowMapper());
        jdbcCursorItemReader.setDataSource(myDataSource);
        jdbcCursorItemReader.setFetchSize(50);
        jdbcCursorItemReader.setVerifyCursorPosition(false);
        jdbcCursorItemReader.setSaveState(false);
        return jdbcCursorItemReader;
    }


    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(50);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(100);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("My-TaskExecutor ");
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(Boolean.TRUE);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("myJob").transactionManager(secondaryTransactionManager)
                .chunk(50).reader(jdbcCursorItemReader())
                .writer(myJpaItemWriter())
                .taskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor)
                .throttleLimit(100)
                .build();
    }
```

The code works fine without multithreading or threadpooltaskexecutor.However, when using them i encounter below error.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: Current position is after the last row
could not execute statement [n/a] com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
```

I have tried using JdbcCursotItemReader, even then i am facing the same error.Any Suggestions on how to make this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JdbcCursorItemReader` is not thread safe because it is based on a `ResultSet` which is not thread safe. The `StoredProcedureItemReader` is also based on a `ResultSet`, hence it is not thread-safe neither. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53964556/5019386

Try to use the `JdbcPagingItemReader` which [is thread-safe](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html) or if you really have to use the `StoredProcedureItemReader`, then make it thread-safe by wrapping it in a `SynchronizedItemStreamReader`.

Hope this helps.