# HibernateCursorItemReader gets non-threadsafe access to the session Error

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, spring-batch

```
@Component
@Scope("step")
public class MyReader implements ItemReader<MyDto>, InitializingBean{
    private HibernateCursorItemReader<Object[]> reader;
    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception{
        reader = new HibernateCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        reader.setUseStatelessSession(true);
        reader.setQueryString(/*query*/);
        //...
    }

    public MyDto read() throws Exception{
        Object[] record = reader.read(); //exception here org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to the session
    }
}
```

When using the `HibernateCursorItemReader`, I got the `org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: possible non-threadsafe access to the session` Exception.

How to fix it?

I need it to run the `read()` so that I can dump the results into a new `MyDto` Object for the writer to process/write. The writer has its own db calls to get other details too.

Comment: Your `MyReader` does not call `open` on the `HibernateCursorItemReader` before calling `read`. This may start using the `HibernateCursorItemReader` in a un-initialized state and can be the cause of your issue. Why don't you use the `HibernateCursorItemReader` directly? What is the added value of your reader?

Answer (score 0):

[As Javadoc says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/HibernateCursorItemReader.html), `HibernateCursorItemReader` is **not thread-safe**.  The problem is not in the class you have posted but in the way you are using it.  Probably you are using it in a multithreaded step but you can't.  Besides using a single-threaded step (obvious), a safe multithreaded solution is to use [async ItemProcessor/ItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html#asynchronous-processors).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/28724199/685806

Comment: @theAnonymous, any feedback? Have you solved the problem?