# Using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor fetching same records from JdbcCursorItemReader in different threads

Tags: multithreading, spring-batch, threadpoolexecutor, chunks

I have a got a problem when I use JdbcCursorItemReader its fetching same records in the threads and skip those nos of equal records.
Suppose there are 2000 records, with chunk size of 500 and below taskexecutor, we getting duplicate records in the all three threads and skip few records with verifyCursorPosition(false)

But, with verifyCursorPosition(true) the o/p that I received is proper but at the end it throws an error **org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unexpected cursor position change.** resulting into FAILED state of the JOB.

Can some one has face same problem or have any alternate solution for the same which includes multiple threads and chunks

```
 `@Bean(name = "SteptaskPool")
 public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor(){
  
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(3); 
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(3);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(8);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("Stepprocess-");
        taskExecutor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(Boolean.TRUE);
  
        return taskExecutor;
 }
```

`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch: problems (mix data) when converting to multithread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28719836/spring-batch-problems-mix-data-when-converting-to-multithread)

Comment: The `JdbcCursorItemReader` is not thread-safe, so it is not correct to use it in a multi-threaded step. See duplicate question for how to make it thread-safe and for more details about alternatives.